# C++ mathematical comparison using function return value not working

Tags: c++, function, math, comparison, return-value

Consider the following code:

```
   char foo[32] = "123456";
   printf("strlen(foo) = %d\n", strlen(foo));
   if ((5 - strlen(foo)) > 0)
   {
      //This statement prints because the comparison above returns true, why?
      printf("String must be less than 5 characters, test 1\n");
   }

   int tmp;
   if ((tmp = 5-strlen(foo)) > 0)
   {
      //This statement does not print and makes since
      printf("String must be less than 5 characters, test 2\n");
   }
```

As the comments indicate, I do not understand why a temporary variable is needed to store the result of the mathematical calculation before comparisons to another value work.

Comment: Your `%d` should be `%zu`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The reason why you get a `true` there is because the result of the subtraction is *unsigned*. This, in turn, is because `size_t`, the return type of `strlen()`, is unsigned, and it's large enough that int got converted to its type rather than the other way around.

When you assign the result of the subtraction to a signed `int` variable `tmp`, you make the result signed again, so the comparison works as expected.

In general, you should be very careful with subtraction of unsigned values if you suspect that the result might become negative. If you are not 100% sure, use a signed type, or avoid subtractions in the first place. For example, a legitimate replacement for your condition above would be

```
if (strlen(foo) <= 5)
    ...
```

Comment: "because size_t, the return type of strlen(), is unsigned" ...and it's large enough that `int` got converted to its type rather than the reverse.

Comment: But why does the assignment modify the result type of the subtraction? Shouldn't the subtraction operation be resolved before assigning to an `int` type?

Comment: @Svalorzen, The subtraction result is unsigned, which is converted when stored in `tmp`.

Comment: @Svalorzen Assignment casts the unsigned result, a very large positive number, to an `int` with its most significant bit set to `1`. I think that the results of casts like this are implementation-defined, but it might be undefined behavior; I'd have to check the standard to see what it is.

Comment: @chris Exactly. If the subtraction result is unsigned, then it cannot be `-1`, but it is going to be a positive number. What type of conversion is applied then?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I was also thinking it may be undefined behaviour, since you are probably overflowing the int, which is not allowed.

Comment: @Svalorzen, It's an implementation-defined value if it cannot fit per §4.7 [conv.integral].

Comment: @Svalorzen It is not a conversion, it is a re-interpretation. The value of `-1` in unsigned is a large value with all bits set to `1`s. When the same value gets set into an `int`, it gets interpreted as `-1` in 2-s complement representation.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight Yes of course. I just wanted to be sure that it is implementation defined, which I believe should be mentioned in the answer, since it seems to be quite important for the result.

Comment: @Svalorzen Signed arithmetic that overflows is undefined. Converting is allowed (§4.7 [conv.integral]/p3 "If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type (and bit-field width); otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.").